# How to move windows CCRC views to UNIX CCRC?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I need to move windows CCRC Views to unix CCRC server, so:

1. What are all the Prerequisite should i have to check ?
2. How to move all user access to Unix CCRC server?
3. how to access CCRC server via windows CCRC client ?

Answer (score 1):

Having done that kind of migration:

- I simply re-installed CCRC server (like any other ClearCase installation, following the [general pre-requisites from the manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_inst_planning_ccrc.htm))
- I didn't have to declare any kind of user access (you just need to make sure the user logins are still valid on the new Unix server: '`id -a auser`' should works.
- Any CCRC client, windows or Linux, will be able to access the new CCRC server, provided they:

  - change the connection address
  - re-create their web views (I din't move the view storages: it was easier for them to recreate what they need)d.

Note: a Unix CCRC server won't be able to access Vob servers on Windows, only Vob servers on Unix.
If your current Windows CCRC was accessing Unix Vob server, then the migration will be easy.
If not, that would mean migrating Vobs from Windows to Unix, and that is quite another task ;)

Comment: Thanks for your idea Von , I have two concerns need to be noticed 
1. I need to map all user with their windows domain login id 
2. I have 1500 web views in running window server; hence Re-creating all web views is still advisable?   
Note: My VOB server on UNIX and all Windows CCRC users was accessing Unix VOB server

Comment: @mth123: 1. you need your nis accounts to match your windows login (i.e. how long are your Windows login? more or less than 8 chars?) 2. Do you need 1500 right from the start? I usually prefer for the user to recreate what they need on a day-to-day basis.